# Copy files to destination folder and also delete any that are not in source folder?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy the folder `Prod` from source to destination, however I want to update the contents of destination with the contents of the source.

```
Prod
|--file 1
|--file 2
```

Destination:

```
Prod
|--file a
|--file b
```

The problem is that since the name of the files are different, when I do copy paste I end up with 4 files: file 1, file2, file a, file b

When I only want the two files from source: file 1 & file 2

Comment: Wanted to note that you should always include your code with a question (even if it doesn't work) we then get an idea what you are trying to do. Also including your code shows that you've tried to solve this yourself and aren't just asking someone else to do it all for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `robocopy` with the `MIR` (Mirror) switch, this will copy files/folders and remove anything in destination that does not exist in source.

```
robocopy C:\source\Prod D:\destination\Prod /MIR
```

Quote from [Technet robocopy wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#Mirror_a_directory_with_subfolders_incl_empty_directories):

> /MIR specifies that Robocopy should mirror the source directory and the destination directory. Note that this will delete files at the destination if they were deleted at the source.

Comment: Thanks James. Exactly what I was looking for. Now sure about why people have down voted it, I felt that this was a useful question when it comes to scripting the powershell deployment or something similar

Comment: Likely downvoted because of the reason I commented on above - that you showed none of your own code or research.